# PDO Informix SQLDriverConnect: -"917"

Tags: php, informix

i have big problem while connection to a remote informix database server.

here's the code

```
$db = new PDO("informix:host=192.168.*.*; service=1565;
database=daten; server=name; protocol=onsoctcp; 
EnableScrollableCursors=1", "informix", "info00");

print "Connection Established!\n\n";

echo "Table contents: $rows.\n";
```

I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -917 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Must close current database before using a new database.' in /var/www/informix.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/informix.php(9): PDO->__construct('informix:host=1...', 'informix', 'info00') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/informix.php on line 9

How can I fix this?

Comment: Superficially, it appears you already had a database open and were trying to open a different database.  But that normally applies to actual `DATABASE xyz` statements, not to the `CONNECT TO 'dbase'` notation that should be being used by the PDO driver.  Your application should not be connecting as 'informix'; that's tantamount to running as 'root' on a Unix box.  Dangerous; powerful but dangerous.  Please don't do it.

Comment: Actually, the previous comments about `DATABASE xyz` vs `CONNECT TO 'dbase'` show my ESQL/C bias; PDO_Informix uses ODBC, of course.  Did you connect to anything before?  Presumably not.  Are you able to connect to a local database successfully (so it is only remote connections that cause trouble)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also set the DB_LOCALE environment variable.
When the client application requests a connection, it sends information, including the DB_LOCALE  to the database server.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.